# How to get the entire HTML source code from webkit control in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

How to get the entire HTML source code from **webkit** control in IOS.

HTML source contains javascript code which will be executed. So only after its executed need to fetch html code.

**For ex:** In below Html code there is a script tag getting created with json type. So this script needs to be created and only then html source needs to fetched.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span>Hello my html sample page</span>
    <div>
        <script>
            var entryTags = "apple, orange, mango, banana";
            var inTime = 10;
            var outTime = 40;
            var etag = document.createElement('script');
            etag.type = 'application/json';
            etag.text = JSON.stringify({
                "author": "Clarke",
                "category": ["apple"],
                "name": "Some sample application",
                "keywords": entryTags.split(","),
                "datePublished": "2010-05-31",
                "inTime": ('PT' + inTime + 'M'),
                "outTime": ('PT' + outTime + 'M'),
            });
            document.querySelector('body').appendChild(etag);
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Current IOS code shown below is not able to fetch it so looking for solution.

```
- (void)fetchHtmlContent {
   NSURL *TheUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@“https://jstesting.azurewebsites.net“];
   [self.htmlView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:TheUrl]];
   [self.htmlView evaluateJavaScript:@“document.documentElement.outerHTML” completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
       if (error == nil)
       {
           if (result != nil)
           {
               NSLog(@“result: %@“, result);
           }
       }
       else
       {
           NSLog(@“evaluateJavaScript error : %@“, error.localizedDescription);
       }
   }];
}
```

Tried with below bold string in `evaluateJavaScript`. Below are the results.

**document.documentElement.outerHTML** - does not give the content inside the body

**document.body.innerHTML** - nothing is displayed

**document.body.outerHTML** - `<body></body>`

but actually I need the html source code.

Comment: evaluateJavaScript needs a javascript string, you are giving it a web address.

Comment: @CodeBender sorry it was typing mistake .. I have updated the post with more information